# Ping grows after heavy traffic - LwIP + Freerthos + Keil

Tags: freertos, lwip

Good day,

We set up device as UDP client/server. Everything work just fine, communication is initialized, device correctly answers on UDP packets.

What is weird that if we start sending packets to device let's say 1 udp packet per 1ms and we let this running for 10 minutes. A ping on device will be around 1ms  which is just fine. But when we suddenly stop transmission ping grows up to ~200ms or even ~600ms. If we re-run transmission of packets ping will decrease to 1-3ms.

What is happening? This seems to be illogical.

Edit: On each UDP packet device answers with another UDP packet which is send as a broadcast.